# How to round a double to two decimals through Formatting, then using the number afterwards?

Tags: java, formatting

Im currently making a program that generates a random number and then calculates the amount of 20 dollar, 1 dollars, quarters, pennys etc it would take to make that number. This is what im using to calculate the double, with `randomValue` being the random double.

```
double rangeMin = 1;
double rangeMax = 100;
Random r = new Random();
double randomValue = rangeMin + (rangeMax - rangeMin ) * r.nextDouble();
```

The problem I have is that it keeps giving me a double with 16 decimal places, so i tried using a formatter

```
Formatter fmt = new Formatter();
fmt.format("%.2f", x);
```

(its x because  I sent `randomValue` through parameters to another class)

now my big problem is i cant use the number i formatted in anything. For example i cant use it in an if statement, as it gives me an error

```
    if(fmt > 1000) {
    System.out.print("it worked");
}
```

i know i cant compare a Formatter to an int in the same way i cant compare strings and longs, but how do i get the random double number i formatted or somehow change it back into a double so that i can use it?

Comment: Step 1: Actually get the formatted value: `String str = fmt.format("%.2f", x);` --- Step 2: Convert it back to a double value: `double x2 = Double.parseDouble(str);`

Answer (score 1):

A lot easier is to multiply everything by `100` and calculate everything using pennies. That way you don't have to deal with floating point and the problems with it. You can still display it in a different way, just do all calculations with pennies and integers. It's a valid technique with all kinds of currency handling (which is a difficult problem).

Formatting is for display purposes only. When you format a number, it becomes a `String`. You can't use a `Formatter` for rounding numbers and calculate with them afterwards.

Comment: dang, i didnt even think about doing it that way, thank you!

Comment: @HaydenPoyfair it's a good technique. Especially when you're dealing with real money and you **can't** have rounding errors or other weirdness in your calculations.

Answer (score 0):

The JavaDoc available right in your IDE has an example usage that should resolve the issue for you.

[image: JavaDoc]

You need to provide the formatter an "out" (StringBuilder), then take the string from there and make your decimal.

I agree with the other answer though, just make a random Integer and divide by 100 to achieve a two decimal point number.

Comment: I didn't say to get a random int and divide it by 100. Not at all.

Comment: @Alan Blyth  ... yeah i tried reading that earlier... i dont really understand it to well.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is first, Formatter is not the value you want and second Formatter is not comparable.

The result of the format method need to be retrieved with the toString()method, to get it as a double you have to use a util method.

```
Formatter fmt = new Formatter();
double value = Double.parseDouble(fmt.format("%.2f", x).toString());
```

Then you compare value instead of 'fmt'

Comment: Please don't use `format` and `parseDouble()` in the same code. It's a lot less reliable than what you assume.

Comment: @Marcos Vasconcleos im getting an error The method parseDouble(String) in the type Double is not applicable for the arguments (Formatter)

Comment: @HaydenPoyfair this isn't a reliable technique. While it will work for some values, some values just can't be represented properly in floating point and you'll end up with a different value after parsing the String.

Comment: @HaydenPoyfair remember to call toString as described here, also consider Kayaman comment, you better not use the rounded value back

Answer (score 0):

As has been said with other comments, the issue is with trying to use `Formatter` instead of a comparable value. You can typically get this from `Double`. You may also find the `DecimalFormat` class applicable here:

```
double money = 85.36121;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("##.##");      
money = Double.valueOf(df.format(money)); //gives 85.36
```